# How can I get the distance, direction, duration from my current location to next step?

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox Android SDK

`compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:3.0.0@aar')`.

I asked the similar question before at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663793/use-googlemap-or-mapbox-direction-api-implement-my-own-navigation-in-my-app), but still have some problem. I don't know how to implement when I get currentRoute. my code is as below:

```
private Waypoint lastCorrectWayPoint;
private boolean checkOffRoute(Waypoint target) {
    boolean isOffRoute = false;
    if(currentRoute != null){
        if (currentRoute.isOffRoute(target)) {
            showMessage("You are off-route, recalculating...");
            isOffRoute = true;
            lastCorrectWayPoint = null;
            //would recalculating route.
        } else {
            lastCorrectWayPoint = target;
            String direction = "Turn right"; //The message what should I prompt to user
            double distance = 0.0;//The distance which from target to next step.
            int duration = 0;//The time which from target to next step.
            String desc = "Turn right to xx street.";
            //Implement logic to get them here.
            showMessage("direction:" + direction + ", distance:" + distance + ", duration:" + duration + ", desc:" + desc);
        }
    }
```

`checkOffRoute()` would be called within `onLocationChanged()`. I think MapBox SDK should provide these data to developer instead of developer implement it by himself. or if I miss something important information in SDK? Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there any convenient  way I can know my current Routestep?  If I can get my current Routestep, I can find my next Routestep by adding Routestep index in steps list. after I get next RouteStep, I can use method computeDistance() to compute the distance  between my current and RouteStep. I think this solution is a weird to developer. why  currentRoute can't return these value or provide a method to developer? I have no idea how to implement this. no found in their document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hope your app is coming along well. I see your trying to get direction, distance, and duration to next step. I'll try and answer this as best I can while keeping it short.

**Direction**
First when you request the route you need to include a couple lines:

```
MapboxDirections client = new MapboxDirections.Builder()
                .setAccessToken(getString(R.string.accessToken))
                .setOrigin(origin)
                .setDestination(destination)
                .setProfile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING)
                .setAlternatives(true) // Gives you more then one route if alternative routes available
                .setSteps(true) // Gives you the steps for each direction
                .setInstructions(true) // Gives human readable instructions
                .build();
```

Once you receive the response you can do something along the lines of

```
response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getSteps().get(0).getDirection()
```

which will give you the approximate cardinal direction of travel following the maneuver. Typically one of the following: 'N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', or 'NW'. This specific line gives you the first route in the list (also typically the shortest and best choice route) and the first step. To change through the steps you simply change the integer value of the second `.get(int)` to whatever step you need.

**Duration and Distance**
Same as above but instead of `.getDirection()` you use:

```
 response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getSteps().get(0).getDuration()
```

and

```
response.body().getRoutes().get(0).getSteps().get(0).getDistance()
```

respectively. I hope this at least helps to guide you in the right direction while creating your app.